# CakePHP - reject requests if application cookie is not set

Tags: cakephp

complete PHP newcomer here. I have a 3rd party PHP application (developed by someone else but I have code to it) that sets a cookie when a user login into its login page. Lets call it MYAPPCOOKIE. I also have a CakePHP based API that enables developers to extract information via an easy to use API.

What I want to do is disable access to the APIs if MYAPPCOOKIE is not set. In other words, rely on the user logged into the portal before I return API values. I know this is a weak authentication mechanism, but I'd really like to start here.

I understand my app and my cake APIs are two different entities. So to get started, I first edited api/app/Config/core.php and added the following line:

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
                'defaults' => 'php',
                'cookie' => 'MYAPPCOOKIE'
        ));
```

I assume this will give my Cake layer access to the same cookie that the main app uses.

Now, how do I go about denying API access if this cookie does not exist? Do I have to go to every controller of every API and do something like

```
$this->Cookie->read('MYAPPCOOKIE');
```

and then do the rest of the work? Or is there a more general way for me to check in the Cake Layer if the instance that is accessing the API also has that cookie set and if not, just return a 4xx for *all* APIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally solved this issue the following way:

a) As it turned out using cookies is a bad idea. There is no way to actually delete a cookie - you can only expire it - the browser decides when to delete it. So even if you change the cookie to have an expired time on logout in the app, the cookie still physically exists and the next time you check isset($_COOKIE[cookiename]) in the cakePHP app, it still exists, which means you can't really use this method to make sure you are logged in to the App (PHP) before you access the API (CakePHP)

b) In my case, the solution was to instead use $_SESSION - the PHP app sets a username and other details when a person is logged in and clears the session when you log out, so to make sure the API ties into the login system of the App, I added the following code to AppController.php:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
        if (!$this->Session->Read('username')) 
        {

            throw new NotFoundException(__('Not Authenticated'));
            return;
        }

    }
```